# ¿Cómo puedo tener más colores disponibles en bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap

estoy usando Bootstrap 4 en su versión alpha (se que hay una más reciente) y tengo una duda. Estoy haciendo una web y estoy usando los menús que trae bootstrap por defecto, pero hay solo 3 colores. Además en otros ámbitos de bootstrap solo hay algunos colores muy limitados. Quiero saber si uno puede ocupar sus colores como cuando hacia las cosas con css, donde colocaba #(color) porque así era totalmente personalizado, en cambio bootstrap solo tiene unos cuantos colores y no me gustan. Gracias.

Comment: Puedes tu mismo escribir los colores mediante css o la otra forma es reescribir los colores que necesites en los archivos de bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

solo debes sobre-escribir las reglas de estilos que tiene por defecto Bootstrap, es totalmente posible, usa tu inspector de desarrollador para conocer con exactitud el selector que utiliza, en la mayoria de exploradores esto lo activas con "click derecho -> inspeccionar elemento -> Inspector", y escoge lo que quieres editar para conocer sus estilos actuales.

Después procede a crear tus propias reglas en un archivo aparte.

Nota** Debes ser lo más exacto posible en tu selector ya que de otra forma puede o no afectarte como tu gustas al elemento.

```
  <ul class="nav">
     <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
     </li>
  </ul>
```

En tu CSS puedes usar el selector

```
.nav > .nav-item > .nav-link 
{
...............
}
```

Para sustituir estilos o colores o lo que gustes.

Comment: Gracias por sus respuestas, lo intentaré y luego les cuento cómo me fue.

Comment: Gracias, cambié los css por defecto de bootsrap y ahora puedo usar otros colores :D

Comment: Perfecto @Pandehuevo , me alegra que haya sido de ayuda!

Comment: @Pandehuevo si te sirvió la respuesta, por favor márcala como aceptada

Answer (score 1):

Si te refieres al color que le puedes dar mediante la clase bg-color solo le puedes dar estos colores

```
primary:#007bff;
secondary:#6c757d;
success:#28a745;
info:#17a2b8;
warning:#ffc107;
danger:#dc3545;
light:#f8f9fa;
dark:#343a40;
```

pero puedes arreglarlo utilizando css ya sea directamente a nivel de etiqueta:

```
<nav class="navbar" style="background-color:#cc0033;">
```

O mediante selectores:

```
<nav class="navbar" id="menu">

<style>
  #menu{
    background-color:#cc0033;
  }
</stile
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente por css, crea una clase y añadeselo al componente, incluso puedes modificar el css de Bootsrap para que ese componente concreto sea del color que deseas.